# Bash for loop with unique var names issue

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

I am using a bash for loop to cycle through a directory and print the file size. My issue though is that I need to assign a unique variable to each of the values so that they can be used later but the array is inputting all the data as one element in the array. I have tried both a double for loop and a if statement with a nested for loop but did not get the right results.
Question: How can I fix the below code to match my needs or is there a better method?

```
declare -a byte
for b in /home/usr/frames/*
do
  byte+=$(wc -c < $b)
done 
declare -p byte
```

Comment: Try usin an associative array e.g. `declare -A byte["$b"]=$(wc -c < "$b")`  instead of normal array indexed array.

Comment: @Jetchisel this isn't quite what I envisioned but it works so thank you. If you know a way to get the array names be like f1, f2, etc please post again.      declare -A byte=([/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames7.png]="12853871" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames5.png]="12691609" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames8.png]="12869799" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames3.png]="12678175" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames1.png]="12618804" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames2.png]="12653975" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames6.png]="12698386" [/home/joe/STENO/REAL/frames/frames4.png]="12828883" )

Comment: I have edited the answer, to extract the file name from the path name, not sure about the array names since byte is the name of the associative array, `array_name[key]=value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A variation on OPs original code and jetchisel's answer:

```
unset byte
declare -A byte                                # -A == associative array

for b in /home/usr/frames/*
do
    byte[$(basename "${b}")]=$(wc -c < "${b}")
done 

declare -p byte
```

---

Using some `*.txt` files on my host:

```
$ pwd
/c/temp/cygwin
$ wc -c *.txt
 22 file.txt
405 somefile.txt
214 test.txt
```

With the modified `for` clause:

```
unset byte
declare -A byte

for b in /c/temp/cygwin/*.txt
do
    byte[$(basename "${b}")]=$(wc -c < "${b}")
done 

declare -p byte
```

Generates:

```
declare -A byte=([somefile.txt]="405" [test.txt]="214" [file.txt]="22" )
```

Answer (score 1):

With associative array (if available)

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for b in /home/usr/frames/*; do
  declare -A byte["$b"]=$(wc -c < "$b")
done
```

---

Use [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to extract just the file name.

```
declare -A byte["${b##*/}"]=$(wc -c < "$b")
```

---

Now check the value of `byte`

```
declare -p byte
```